# Where to put username and password of WebClient of Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I try to make Spring WebFlux security application with router and handler classes. First, below codes are the configuration codes of WebFlux security.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class BlogWebFluxSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        
        UserDetails userWebFlux = User.withUsername("joseph").password("password").roles("USER").build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(userWebFlux);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/route/user/all", "/route/post/all").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/route/user/**", "/route/post/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
        
        return http.build();
    } 
}
```

And the next codes are about the router class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class BlogWebFluxEndpointRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routesUser(UserHandler handler) {
        
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/user/all"), handler::findAll)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/user/id/{id}"), handler::findById)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/user/username/{username}"), handler::findByUsername)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/user/email/{email}"), handler::findByEmail)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.POST("/route/user/create"), handler::register)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/user/login/{username}/{password}"), handler::authenticate);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routesPost(PostHandler handler) {
        
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/post/all"), handler::findAll)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/post/id/{id}"), handler::findById)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/post/delete/{id}"), handler::deleteById)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.POST("/route/post/create"), handler::create)
                    .andRoute(RequestPredicates.PUT("/route/post/{id}/{content}"), handler::edit);
    }
}
```

Even the network is REST web service, But I use `WebClient` class of WebFlux.

```java
public void functionOnUserDocument() { 
    client.get().uri("/route/user/all").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).exchange()
            .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(User.class))
            .subscribe(u -> System.out.println("All Users : " + u.getUsername() + ":" + u.getEmail() + ":" + u.getFullname()));
    
    client.get().uri("/route/user/id/{id}", "0002").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(User.class))
            .subscribe(u -> System.out.println("GET by Id : " + u.getUsername() + ":" + u.getEmail() + ":" + u.getFullname()));
    
    client.get().uri("/route/user/username/{username}", "jina").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(User.class))
            .subscribe(u -> System.out.println("Get by username : " + u.getUsername() + ":" + u.getEmail() + ":" + u.getFullname()));

    client.get().uri("/route/user/email/{email}", "myson@college.ac.kr").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(User.class))
            .subscribe(u -> System.out.println("Get By Email : " + u.getUsername() + ":" + u.getEmail() + ":" + u.getFullname()));
    
    client.get().uri("/route/user/login/{username}/{password}", "julian", "password").exchange()
            .map(ClientResponse::statusCode).subscribe(response -> System.out.println("Login : " + response.getReasonPhrase()));
    
    User user = new User("0005", 4L, "jane", "password", "aaa@bbb.com", "누나", "USER");

    client.post().uri("/route/user/create").body(Mono.just(user), User.class).exchange() 
            .map(ClientResponse::statusCode).subscribe(response -> System.out.println("User Creation: " + response.getReasonPhrase()));
}
```

Because I make the WebFlux security configuration, definitely some `WebClient` can not be executed and forbidden like below:

```
Login : Unauthorized
User Creation: Forbidden
```

I do not use cURL. So what I want to know is what my `WebClient` methods are to be, where username and password have to be located and transferred to `WebClient` class.

Comment: you have several bad things in your code, you NEVER subscribe in a webflux application so all `subscribe` needs to be removed. And i have no idea what your question is. It when people call your service, or when your service calls another service?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You mean which part of my source has BAD thing? Router or WebClient? Kindly inform me the reference site as well as the my mistakes.

Comment: your service is a `publisher`, all clients calling it are `subscribers`. So you should not use `subscribe`

Comment: you should never `/route/user/login/{username}/{password}` this will send usernames and passwords over the internet free for everyone to see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142695/is-a-plain-password-in-the-url-a-potential-security-threat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTP Basic authentication expects the username and password encoded in Base64 format in `Authorization` header. Also, you don't need to have a login endpoint since this information should be sent with every request.

Add the Basic Auth header to each call in your client like the following:

```
String basicAuthHeader = "basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes())

client.get().uri("/route/user/all")
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, basicAuthHeader)
      .exchange()
      .flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(User.class))
      .subscribe(u -> System.out.println("All Users : " + u.getUsername() + ":" + u.getEmail() + ":" + u.getFullname()));
```

Answer (score 30):

Since spring 5.1 you should set basic authentication with [`HttpHeaders#setBasicAuth`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#setBasicAuth-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), like this:

```
webClient
    .get()
    .uri("https://example.com")
    .headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth("username", "password"))
    .exchange()
    ....
```

the previous approach, of using [`.filter(basicAuthentication("user", "password")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunctions.html#basicAuthentication-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), is now deprecated.

Comment: This approach also works for the [RestClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClient.html) which was introduced in [Spring 6.1](https://spring.io/blog/2023/07/13/new-in-spring-6-1-restclient).

Answer (score 7):

Spring provides API for supplying basic authentication parameters to your WebClient via [ClientFilters](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-filter).

You can achieve the same result of having `Authorization` header set up with less custom coding.

Please see code snippet below from spring docs:

```
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunctions.basicAuthentication;

    WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
            .filter(basicAuthentication("user", "password"))
            .build();
```